# How to get data between start date and enddate

Tags: hql, webflux

This is the query:

```
" select dbo from EmpWorkDiaryEntriesDBO dbo"
                          + "lef join fetch dbo.empWorkDiaryEntriesDetailsDBOSet dbos"
                          + "where dbo.recordStatus='A' and dbo.erpWorkEntryDate between (:startDate) 
                              and (:endDate) order by erpWorkEntryDate ASC ";
```

And this is the error

```
getting eror expecting EOF, found ')'
```

Comment: "lef join"? add some spaces to your strings, cause you get "... EntriesDBO dbolef join ..."

Comment: Its probably a spacing issue and ofcourse it must be "left join"